# PhoneGap emulator error: ios-deploy was not found

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have installed phonegap and all works fine with android emulator...instead for ios:
phonegap run ios
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

```
[phonegap] successfully compiled iOS app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
Error: ios-deploy was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.0.4 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy into your path. Or 'npm install -g ios-deploy' using node.js: http://nodejs.org/
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
 [warning] missing ios-sim
 [warning] install ios-sim from http://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim
Error: ios-sim was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.7 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim into your path. Or 'npm install -g ios-sim' using node.js: http://nodejs.org/
   [error] /Users/riccardo/Desktop/selfiefit/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I have installed with npm ios-deploy and ios-slim, but still I get the same error...where I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and type `sudo npm install -g ios-sim` in your Terminal. You should see "Build Succeeded" towards the end of your log.

Follow the instructions on [github.com/phonegap/ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim)

Comment: I got "Build Succeeded" message at the end of log..but ../cordova/run generated still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the instructions on [ios sim installation](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim#installation)

```
npm install -g ios-sim
DevToolsSecurity -enable
sudo ps -A | grep -e "launchd_sim" -e "simulator" -i | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

Ensure that the emulator is closed and re run the emulator